# Relationship between f(X) and f(closure of X)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to prove **if f is continuous and closed ("closed" means the image of any closed subset of the domain is closed) then f(closure of X) equals the closure of f(X).** I was able to prove that if f is continuous then f(closure of X) is a subset of closure of f(X). Now, I am trying to prove the other way around: closure of f(X) is a subset of f(closure of X). So here is my attempt:

Let y be a point of the closure of f(X). Then y is either a point of f(X) or a limit point of f(X). **I am wondering if f(X) is a subset of f(closure of X)?**
If this is true then in the former case, it is easy to conclude that y is also a point of f(closure of X) and in the latter case, I can show that y is also a limit point of f(closure of X). Since f is a closed mapping and the closure of X is closed, f(closure of X) is also closed, which implies y is a point of f(closure of X).

Also, if you know how to prove that
**if f(closure of X) equals closure of f(X) then f is a continuous and closed mapping**
I would really appreciate it if you could give me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $X \subset Y$, then $f(X) \subset f(Y)$.

Comment: thanks. I thought so too but I was not sure...:)

Answer (score 1):

$f(X)$ is surely a subset of $f(\bar{X})$ since $X$ is a subset of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: cool beans :):)